# Pulling Down Gitlab Repo Information in REACT

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab

I'm currently working on a GUI utilizing REACT (node.js backend) and I want to create a page that pulls repo file names from a specific Gitlab repo (my own repo). So I would press a button and up comes a sub-window showing the Repo data pulled. I intend to use this to grab the name of the file and store it for later use on another part of the GUI.

I am new to REACT and I'm still learning it. My question is how would I go about grabbing the information as far as coding goes? I imagine the Gitlab REACT API would be what I want to use for starters. I've seen videos where they create a page to search data from different repos such as Giblab users, but I could not find the same for searching for repo file structures.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean “what api to use to grab repo files” or “how to call the api in react”?

Comment: I know there is a Gitlab API to use for REACT (pretty sure its functional with nodejs), would I have to use something else? If that's what I would use the question would be "how to call the API" 
Thanks for the reply!